# Dynamically load a modal containing iframe on click?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, bootstrap-modal

I need a modal containing an iframe (which is a complete external page) to populate a Bootstrap modal window, the problem is the page is very large so I don't want it to load until the modal event is fired. Is this possible with jQuery/Bootstrap?

Comment: So you want the modal to pop with nothing while the user waits?  Wouldn't a better UX be to load the page in the background after the page has initially loaded so if the modal pops, the content is available as soon as possible?

Comment: No, I don't want the added bloat to page unless it is clicked. The majority of users won't be clicking it and the site has heavy mobile traffic and I don't want to over burden mobile devices or fuss with responsive javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep just set the `src` attribute:

```
$("#youriframe").attr("src", url);
```

Although if possible I would preload the iframe (as someone mentioned in the comments) before the modal is clicked open to reduce the time that the user has to wait.

If you want to clear the iframe when the modal is closed just set the `src` attribute to "about:blank".